How can I test if a string contains a character in busybox sh?
I want to add an extension to a filename when it does not have one. I tried to determine whether the string contains a period but this did not work.
#!/bin/sh

dest=$2
if [ "$dest" != "." ]; then
    dest="$dest".tar.gz
fi

ShellCheck complained that my script cannot support the if [[ condition ]].
What condition will determine whether a period is contained? The environment is using the BusyBox library.

For /bin/sh you should be using case $dest in *.*) :;; *) dest="$dest".tar.gz;; esac

See How to test if string matches a regex in POSIX shell (not bash) -- what you want is a glob-style pattern, not a regex, but that's true of the OP there too, they just were calling the thing by the wrong name.

or if [ "$dest" = "${dest#*.}" ]; ...

I prefer the if [ ] answer but do not understand all of its syntax, especially '*.'.
